# Django Models. Отношение один к списку

Tags: python, django

На dbdiagram_io написал схему базы данных. Подскажите пожалуйста, как описать модели Django для такой структуры БД? В частности интересует момент описания поля отношения 1 к списку без дополнительной таблицы соотвествия.
В данном случае mmg_datasets.files_list хранит перечень id из mmg_files. Схема:

````
table mmg_files {
  id int [pk]
  study_instance_UID varchar
  path varchar
  side char
  projection varchar
}

table mmg_datasets {
  id int [pk]
  name varchar
  file_list varchar[] [ref: > mmg_files.id]
  comment varchar
  
}

table mmg_metrics {
  id int [pk]
  calc_type varchar // указатель на тип рассчётов- с birads|без WB3|B3|B4
  metric_type varchar // указатьна тип метрики BRM|MLM|RSM
  dataset_id int [ref: > mmg_datasets.id]
  auc float [null]
  npr float
  npv float
  ppr float
  ppv float
  recall float
  specificity float
  accuracy float
  f1_macro float [null]
  fp int
  fn int
  tp int
  tn int
}  ```
````

Comment: Один к списку, это значит один ко многим? Один ко многим в django реализуется с помощью ForeignKey.

Comment: является ли это  отношение "Один ко многим"? теоретически да. Будет ли при этом структура базы такой как на схеме - скорее нет. Отсюда и вытекает вопрос - как правильно описать модели под такую схему.

Comment: Логически решение выглядит примерно так: 
```myArray = ArrayField(
            models.ForeignKey(customModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE),size=8)``` 
Но вызывает ошибку с сообщением о том что ArrayField не может быть связанным полем

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось, абсолютно точно подстроиться под такую структуру БД не получилось, но логически модели выглядят так:
Вполне подошло решение на основе связи ManyToMany.

```
class File(models.Model):
    ...


class Metric(models.Model):
    ...
    dataset = models.ForeignKey('Dataset', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    ...


class Dataset(models.Model):
    ...
    file_list = models.ManyToManyField(File)
    ...
```